# Any component doesn't render after importing react-bootstrap library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

After `npm init` and installation of react, react-dom, bootstrap and react-bootstrap packages, I can't import any component from react-bootstrap library, as `import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';` produce `TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: react-bootstrap/Button`.

I get rid of that error by changing the path to `import Button from './node_modules/react-bootstrap/Button'` - it's correct path, but when I try to render **anything** it doesn't change the div in target .php file, there's not any error in the console, so I lost. I use Babel `babel-cli@6 babel-preset-react-app@3` preprocessor for JSX translation.

Here is preprocessed index.js:

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'


class ProfilePage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>blah blah blah blah blah</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ProfilePage/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

and index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">


<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <link
   rel="stylesheet"
   href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
   integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
   crossorigin="anonymous"
 />

 <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>

</head>


<body>


  <div id="app">inner html
  </div>


  <script
    src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"
    crossorigin
  />
  <script>var Alert = ReactBootstrap.Alert;</script>

  <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script> <!-- processed index.js --> 

</body >
```

Output is: `inner html`.
Without react-bootstrap import it works perfectly, bootstrap also, but of course I'm not able to use react-bootstrap components. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think your import syntax is just off.  Instead of

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
```

Try

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap’
```

Or

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
```

if the above doesn’t work.

Comment: I tried those and numerous possible variations and it's still the same. I have to provide `/` or `./` in the front of the path to eliminate `TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: react-bootstrap/Button`. Maybe it's something with npm configuration? I didn't use it earlier. Just typed `npm init` named project and left rest default, then installed packages I mentioned and think it should work... ?

Comment: Oh.. well why don't you just add / in front of your path?  It must be specified somewhere the relative path for modules, and there must not be a slash at the end there (I'd recommend adding it there so you never need it again)